# How do I set the height of every td element to it's width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a table with the width 100%. It has seven columns that divide up the width equally. All I want to do is to have the height of a td element be equal to it's dynamic width.

Any ideas? jquery is fine

```
table { width: 100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code:

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
  $('table>tr').height($('table>td').width());
});
```

But. It is batter to do it with CSS. Because redraw using javascript is expensive computation.

Comment: Op is looking for cell elements, not the TABLE and btw needs to be dynamic (responsive i guess)

Comment: @A.Wolff Sorry it is my mistake I update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try ...

```
var w = $("table td").width() + "px";
$("table td").css({ height: w });
```